# PHP script which will enter the data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 fieldnames called *ID*, *Autore*, *Titolo* in Mysql. The tablename is *demo* and database name is *forms1*
 I have problem to insert data from many forms into database.
I test code but i have something wrong into *insert.php*

**Form Code:**

```
<style>
br {margin-bottom:-10px;}
</style>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<b>Titolo </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Titolo"><br><br>
<b>Autore </b><input type="text" name="Autore"><br><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

**Insert.php**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES
('', 'Autore', 'Titolo')";


if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

This piece of code is wrong:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES
    ('', 'Autore', 'Titolo')";
```

When i try insert values like Jack, John from form the values that are adding are Autore and Titolo
But Autore & Titolo are my 2nd-3rd fieldnames in my demo table, but its are added like values! 
[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img831/3109/insertdatadatabase.png]

This is my **ResultPage.php**

```
<html>
<?php
echo "<h2>Lista Autori</h2>";  
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
echo "<td width='auto' align='center'>N</td>";  
echo "<td width='auto' >&nbsp;Nome</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    //1. Connessione al Database
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$connection){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
    //2. Seleziona Database
$db_select = mysql_select_db("forms1",$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
    //3. Interroga Database

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo LIMIT 0, 30 ", $connection);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

    //4. Use Returned Data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center' width='auto'>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[2] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";     
    echo "</tr>";

    }

mysql_close($connection);
?>
</html>
```

**How can i change insert.php file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your sql query got problem. it should be like this :

```
$autore = $_POST['Autore'];
$titolo = $_POST['Titolo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo(Autore, Titolo) VALUES ('$autore', '$titolo')";
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: But if i want remove value like Jack or John from form?

Comment: i dont get what u trying to ask there

Comment: mmm..i want remove values like jack or john from database. I try using your code replace INSERT INTO with DELETE FROM but i can't remove jack or john from mysql. How can i do using your solution?

Comment: i dont clearly get what u trying to do, but i hope this will help u 

DELETE FROM demo WHERE Autore = 'Jack' OR Titolo = 'John'

Comment: from form i can add insert data. In this case i want remove data from form..so how generic code can i use?

Comment: if u want to delete data, can use the DELETE statement i posted in previous comment

Comment: thanks, it works, but if i have 100 words to delete. I must enter into mysql?

Comment: Really do not use this answer! At least accept an answer from someone who escapes the user input....

Answer (score 3):

In your insertion code you have

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES 
('', 'Autore', 'Titolo')"
```

This has hardcoded your values.

Do remember to check the values of the variables coming back and escape them

Your form has this:

```
<b>Titolo </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Titolo"><br><br>  
<b>Autore </b><input type="text" name="Autore"><br><br>
```

So the forms sending you

```
$_POST["Titolo"] and $_POST["Autore"]
```

So you should change your

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES 
('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Autore"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Titolo"])."')"
```

and to delete the entered items (both boxes would need to be a proper match)

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM demo where Titolo='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Autore"])."' and Autore='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Titolo"])."';
```

Comment: But if i want remove value like Jack or John from form?

Comment: INSERT TO to insert data, DELETE FROM..i try to replace but doesn't work

Comment: what are the names of your 2 fields you are populating, and I'll update the code.

Comment: i have 3 fields **ID** (int, autoincrement), **Autore** (varchar, null) **Titolo** (varchar, null). You can condiderate only Autore and Titolo

Comment: Have you lost your `)` key? :)

Comment: thanks, it works, but if i have a long list of words to insert/delete? I'm forced to enter into the database?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the php website for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES
    ('', 'Autore', 'Titolo')";

In this query you have to insert the values which is getting from the form not the 'Autore', 'Titolo'

Answer (score 0):

Use these markup for the query:

```
INSERT INTO demo(Autore, Titolo)
VALUES ($_POST['Autore'], $_POST['Titolo'])
```

That way, there saved in the right column... maybe this helps

But be aware, that if you use this, your query is unsafe. You need to strip quotes and all that other stuff...

Answer (score 0):

```
$Autore = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['Autore']);
$Titolo = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['Titolo']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES
    ('', '$Autore', '$Titolo')";
```

Comment: and if i want remove from Form?

Comment: use auto increment Id in the Table from that you can remove or delete entry from table like DELETE FROM demo where id = 1

Comment: `$sql = "DELETE FROM demo VALUES..` seems doesnt work "You have an error in your SQL syntax.."

Comment: VALUES should not come with the DElELTE query. you should use WHERE clause

Comment: I see in mysql this example of code `DELETE FROM 'forms1'.'demo' WHERE 'demo'.'ID' = 20;` but i must replace `'ID' = 20;` with `Autore = Jack;` ?

Comment: While deleting u should use Auto id otherwise it will give problem

Comment: ok..but if i want find a specific word like John or jack how can i modify?

Comment: Update demo SET Autore = 'Jack New' WHERE Autore = 'Jack'

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you did not miss anything!?

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO demo VALUES('', '%s', '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Titolo"]),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Autore"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore all previous answers. Your code is a security disaster. At least ditch the mysql_* functions and use Mysqli or PDO

Did you notice the large area in the php manual:

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   related FAQ for more information.

MySQLi Example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO demo VALUES (?,?,?)");
$val1='';
$autore=$_POST['Autore']; //TODO check if these POST values exist
$titolo=$_POST['Titolo'];
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $val1, $autore, $titolo);


/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Even more reason to start with the current technology and not use something that will stop working in the near future. I'll update my answer with a small example.

Comment: thanks for your example. I try to understand to improve my code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code . You have to capture the actual value before inserting

```
 $Autore = $_post['Autore'];
 $Titolo = $_post['Titolo'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (ID, Autore, Titolo) VALUES  ('', '$Autore', '$Titolo')";
```

Comment: thanks..now i want remove the input data like Jack or John. How can I modify your code? **$sql = "DELETE FROM  demo (ID, Autore, Titolo)** seems doesn't work.

Comment: `$_post` needs to be uppercase and if you aren't going to secure the post data you should add a note to the answer to say it's unsecure.